# Mono c# TextView Buffer Deserialize Keeps Crashing

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I can not figure out why this keeps crashing! I have this inserted into a method that presents the FileChooser allows the user to choose a file and then if file was chosen run this piece of code. I have commented out the lines run the program and systematically and tracked it down to the buffer.Deserialize line. It will run and not crash until this line is added. Of coarse the TextView Buffer Text does not every get updated.

Also Before you comment the file that is opened is a valid saved file and the method to serialize and save file works flawlessly. It is just the problem with opening that crashes.

```
byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileChooser.Filename);

TextBuffer buffer = new TextView().Buffer;
Gdk.Atom serialFormat = buffer.RegisterDeserializeTagset(null); 
ulong length = (ulong) data.LongLength; 
TextIter iterator = buffer.StartIter; 
buffer.Deserialize ( buffer, serialFormat, ref iterator, data, length );
```

For those of you who want to be wise guys and say it is the saved file here is the saved file I am trying to open that crashes it. Well any file crashes it but this is my test file.

```
GTKTEXTBUFFERCONTENTS-0001   Î <text_view_markup>
 <tags>
  <tag id="0" priority="0">
   <attr name="weight" type="gint" value="700" />
  </tag>
 </tags>
<text><apply_tag id="0">
Bold
</apply_tag>Hello World!</text>
</text_view_markup>
```

**Update:** I made some more modifications to try and get some debug information out of the program as the way it was running it was just crashing and giving nothing of value when it crashed. I now get this from the Debugger.

```
GLib.GException: Line 8 character 1: Anonymous tag found and tags can not be created. at Gtk.TextBuffer.Deserialize(TextBuffer content_buffer, Atom format, TextIter& iter, Byte[] data, UInt64 length)
```

Comment: That file is definitely not a binary serialized file. How did you create it? Edit: Seems to be a custom method. How did you create it?

Comment: What is the crash/exception/error message?

Comment: It was create using
byte[] data = mainEditor.Buffer.Serialize(mainEditor.Buffer, format, iterator1, iterator2);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes( fileChooser.Filename, data );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to stop the crashing but now have other issues with trying to get it to run correctly. The original question is no longer the problem.

Solved the original by changing

to this code

```
private string mimeType = "text/plain";
...
buffer.Deserialize ( 
                    mainEditor.Buffer, 
                    mainEditor.Buffer.RegisterDeserializeTagset(mimeType), 
                    ref iterator, 
                    data, 
                    (ulong)data.LongLength
                );
```

It needed a proper mimeType otherwise it crashed, even though the documentation says it would except null as a valid option!